# Язык C, локальные автоматические массивы

Tags: c

Никогда не думал, что для локального автоматического массива справедливо следующее:

```
void func(void)
{
    char arr[10];
    if (arr == &arr)
    {
        // Всегда истина, по крайней мере, при использовании компилятора MinGW.
    }
}
```

Подскажите, Стандарт что-нибудь говорит об этом, или это не более, чем совпадение?

Самое интересное во всей этой ситуации, что следующий код корректно работает:

```
char arr[10];
scanf("%10s", &arr);
```

И я уже было предположил, что компилятор тихо опускает операцию взятия адреса (&), и &arr преобразуется в arr или, если точнее, в &arr[0].

Если бы не одно но:

```
char arr[10];
char *p = &arr;// Warning, несоответствие типов
char **pp = &arr;// Warning, несоответствие типов
```

Так что происходит?

Comment: Просто синонимы. Как имя функции автоматически преобразуется в адрес, так и с массивами...

Comment: да, только типы то на самом деле разные. Поэтому, просто так сравнивать можно, но не стоит

Comment: Обнаружил этот момент, когда случайно подставил в scanf() не arr, а &arr. И оно работает. Вот меня и интересует, как воспринимать такую особенность.

Comment: имя массива почти всегда является адресом начала массива.

Comment: Так сложность не в том, что адрес массива - это адрес его первого элемента, а в том, что для автоматического массива arr и &arr являются синонимами. Получается, мы берем адрес адреса...

Comment: Автоматический массив это с new или без?

Comment: Автоматический массив - массив на стеке. Все его называют статическим, но это название может вводить в заблуждение. Вообще, описанная особенность со взятием адреса массива относится и к массивам, объявленным в глобальной области видимости, а не только к автоматическим, которые создаются на стеке.

Comment: @KoVadim: Язык С не допускает прямое сравнение таких разных типов. Поэтому не, просто так сравнивать нельзя.

Comment: я знаю. Но чистый си закрывает глаза на многие вещи.

Comment: @KoVadim: Именно чистый С запрещает такое сравнение. Его "разрешение" - это заслуга компиляторно-зависимого суржика, к чистому С относящегося весьма опосредованно. Однако мне навскидку не известны компиляторы, закрывающие на это глаза.

Comment: я понял проблему. Мы по разному понимаем слово "запрещает". Для меня запрещает - если не компилируется. Для Вас - если в стандарте написано. К тому же, мы не уточняли, о каком именно компиляторе мы говорим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операция взятия адреса `&`, примененная к массиву, дает вам адрес всего массива. Нет ничего удивительно в том, что адрес всего массива `&arr` численно совпадает с адресом нулевого элемента массива `&arr[0]` (выражение `arr` в этом контексте эквивалентно `&arr[0]`). Точно так же адрес первого элемента структуры совпадает с адресом всей структуры. В этом тоже нет ничего удивительного.

Вот в таком примере вы увидите одинаковые адреса в каждом `printf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S
{
  int a, b, c;    
};

int main()
{
  int a[10];
  printf("%p %p\n", (void *) &a, (void *) a);

  struct S s;
  printf("%p %p\n", (void *) &s, (void *) &s.a);
}
```

Причины одинаковости адресов в каждом `printf` - совершенно идентичные. Почему вас это удивило - не ясно.

---

Однако:

Первый вопрос бессмыслен ибо код некорректен с точки зрения языка С.

Ограничения на операнды оператора `==`

> **Constraints**
>   **2** One of the following shall hold:
>   — both operands have arithmetic type;
>   — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
>   — one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void; or
>   — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

Ваши операнды имеют типы `char *` и `char (*)[10]` и не удовлетворяют вышеприведенным требованиям. Язык С не допускает прямого сравнения указателей типа `char *` и типа `char (*)[10]`.

Вы могли бы сравнить `if ((void *) arr == (void *) &arr)` и действительно получить равенство. Но в этом не ничего удивительного, как сказано выше.

---

Код

```
char arr[10];
scanf("%10s", &arr);
```

не "корректно работает", а порождает неопределенное поведение. Спецификатор формата `%s` требует аргумента типа `char *`, а вы передаете `char (*)[10]`. Поведение не определено.

Практическую "работоспособность" этот код имеет из-за названной выше причины: адрес первого элемента массива совпадает с адресом всего массива.

---

Также по теме скопирую свой ответ [отсюда](http://www.cyberforum.ru/c-beginners/thread1267080-page2.html#post6780567):

```
char mass[N];
scanf("%s",mass); // так правильно
scanf("%s",&mass); // почему-то тоже срабатывает
```

Такой вопрос обычно возникает у людей, которые считают, что массив физически представлен неким указателем на некий блок памяти. Соответственно ожидается , что `&mas` даст нам указатель на этот указатель и не будет работать в `scanf`. Поэтому работоспособность такого `scanf` зачастую вызывает удивление.

На самом деле массивы в языке С не являются и никогда не являлись указателями. Это очень популярная легенда, которая никак не хочет умирать, несмотря на то, что материалов, объясняющих семантику С массивов написано очень много на всех языках.

Массив - это просто непрерывный блок памяти, содержащий элементы массива. Т.е. например `int a[20]` - это блок памяти из 20 объектов типа `int`. И все. Имя `a`, как объект - это объект типа `int [20]`, который соответствует именно и только этому блок памяти. Никакого указателя там нигде нет.

Иллюзия того, что массив "является указателем" возникает из-за того, что когда вы используете имя массива в выражениях, то почти всегда к массиву применяется неявное преобразование типа, которое автоматически "на лету" преобразует объект типа "массив" к временному значению "указатель на элемент". Этот указатель является rvalue и нигде не хранится в памяти. Он существует только концептуально - как результат вышеупомянутого неявного преобразования. Это чисто воображаемый указатель.

По-английски явление "превращения" массива в указатель известно под устойчивым названием "array type decay". В стандарте языка С++ (где ситуация с массивами точно такая же) это неявное преобразование официально называется "array-to-pointer conversion".

Но это неявное преобразование применяется не всегда. В языке С существует три контекста-исключения, в которых это неявное преобразование не делается:

1. Оператор `sizeof`. Как известно `sizeof(array)` возвращает размер всего массива, а не размер указателя на элемент.
2. Унарный оператор `&`. Возвращает указатель типа "указатель-на-весь-массив", а не "указатель-на-указатель"
3. Инициализация массива строковым литералом - `char a[] = "Hello";`. Литерал `"Hello"` является массивом , но не деградирует до указателя в данном контексте.

Таким образом, применение оператора `&` к объекту типа "массив" дает вам указатель "на весь массив" (с точки зрения типа указателя). Т.е. для `int a[20]` выражение `&a` имеет тип `int (*)[20]`. В памяти адрес "всего массива" - это адрес того самого непрерывного блока, о котором я говорил выше. Т.е. численно этот адрес совпадает с адресом нулевого элемента массива. Именно поэтому выражения `&a`, `&a[0]` и просто `a` численно дают один и тот же адрес.

Именно поэтому, к примеру, в функцию `memcpy` для двух массивов (т.е. именно объектов типа "массив", а не "указатель") можно вызывать и как `memcpy(dst, src, sizeof src)`, и как `memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof src)` и как `memcpy(&dst[0], &src[0], sizeof src)`. Результат будет один и тот же во всех случаях.

Именно поэтому правильно работает `scanf` при использовании `mass` или `&mass`, ибо оба выражения дают одно и то же физическое численное значение. (Второй вариант формально не верен, т.к. формат `%s` требует указателя именно типа `char *`, а не `char (*)[N]`, но на практике это не важно.)

Кстати, Денис Ритчи в своей статье об истории происхождения С (http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html) пишет, что изначально он собирался реализовать массивы в С точно так же, как они были реализованы в языках B и BCPL. В B и BCPL массивы были реализованы именно как самостоятельные указатели, указывающие на отдельные посторонние блоки памяти. Но Ритчи также хотел ввести в язык такой новый тип, как структуры. И тут сразу возникла проблема: если массив будет реализован через указатель, то структуру, содержащую в себе массивы, невозможно будет тривиально копировать. Т.е. обычный `memcpy` будет тупо копировать указатели из одной структуры в другую. А это, разумеется, неприемлемо. По этой причине он отказался от идеи реализовывать массивы через физические указатели. Массивы в С стали просто блоками памяти. Никаких указателей. Но для сохранения похожей на B и BCPL семантики в язык С было введено неявное преобразование из типа "массив" в тип "указатель". Большинство операций с массивами работает именно через это преобразование, т.е. через временный указатель. Но физически этого указателя не существует.

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь я разобрался. Возможно, причина моего непонимания кроется в том, что 99% кода использует массивы, память под которые выделяется на куче, поэтому в голове прочно укоренилась мысль, что массив связан с указателем на массив.

Answer (score 2):

#### Стандарт C99

> **6.3.2.1/3**
>
> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a
>   string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is
>   converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of
>   the array object and is not an lvalue.

#### Вольный перевод:

> Если выражение не является аргументом оператора `sizeof` или унарного оператора `&`, то выражение типа «массив элементов *типа*» преобразуется к типу «указатель на *тип*», который указывает на начальный элемент данного массива, и не является *lvalue*.

Т.е. согластно стандарту, левая часть  `(arr == &arr)` раскрывается в указатель на первый аргумент `arr` (тип `char *`), а вторая по обычным правилам оператора `&` в указатель на массив (тип `char (*)[10]`). Учитывая то что представляют из себя Си'шные массивы, они всегда будут указывать на один участок памяти, и в любой реализации должны быть равны.

Но эти выражения не являются синонимами в следствии того, что у них различаются типы. А компиляторы Си в отличие от плюсов допускает такие вольности как сравнения разнотипных указателей, хотя любой компилятор должен был бы чихнуть на манер:

```
warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
```

Comment: Большой спасибо.